# Set bluetooth to discoverable mode

Tags: python, bluetooth

I want to set a bluetooth device to discoverable mode.  I wrote the following code using pybluez, but it just advertises the service.  How do I set discoverable mode so an Android device can find it?

```
uuid = "94f39d29-7d6d-437d-973b-fba39e49d4ee"
advertise_service(
    server_sock, "SampleServer",
    service_id = uuid,
    service_classes = [uuid, SERIAL_PORT_CLASS],
    profiles = [SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE], 
    # protocols = [OBEX_UUID] 
)
```

Comment: This is Bluetooth LE?

Answer (score 0):

Type:

> $ bluetoothctl

And after that:

> $ discoverable on

Your device will now be discoverable for one minute.